# SQL: find dates with no record

Tags: sql, is-empty

I have a table `ORDERS`, there is a field `DATE_ADD`, date format is `2010-02-28 20:48:09`. I need to find out the dates where there has been no order. I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` HAVING COUNT(date_add) < 1
```

but it returns 0 results although there must be some. Where am I wrong here in this query?

Comment: `HAVING` is the partner of `GROUP BY`. Try using them together

Comment: how many field u have ?..i mean columns ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(date_add), COUNT(date_add) AS cnt FROM `orders` GROUP BY DATE(date_add) HAVING COUNT(date_add) < 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't query the `orders` table for data that it *doesn't* contain.  Or, to phrase, this differently, you need a table of all available dates.  If you have a calendar table, then you do such a query as:

```
select c.*
from calendar c left outer join
     (select distinct cast(date_add as date) as date_add
      from orders
     ) o
     on c.date = o.date_add
where o.date_add is null
```

Note:  You need to convert `date_add` to a date (removing the time portion).  This varies by database.  The above is SQL Server syntax.  It could also be something like `date(date_add)` (MySQL) or `trunc(date_add)` (Oracle) or something else.

If you don't have a calendar table, then creating one is very database specific.  If almost all dates have orders, you can do a trick like this:

```
select driver.dte
from (select dte
      from (select distinct cast(date_added + n.n as date) as dte
            from orders
           ) o cross join
           (select 0 as n union all select 1 as n union all select 2 as n
           )
     ) driver left outer join
     (select distinct cast(date_add as date) as date_add
      from orders
     ) o
     on driver.dte = o.date_add
where o.date_add is null
```